# Selector does not contain a main type eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-10

I am trying to run a Java main class from a java project in eclipse which has a dependency on a third party jar and I get the error that

```
Selector does not contain a main type
```

Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
JDK - openjdk 11 amd64

This happens only when I place add the external jar in the class path (not module path) and reference it in my main class

Also I did not create any module info java file while creating java project

Has it got something to do with eclipse and jdk versions ?

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed when I changed java run time environment java SE 8 under project settings.